# Hasua GraphQL docker engine hammering jwk endpoint

Tags: firebase, docker, hasura

I'm using firebase for the jwk, my docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.4.0-beta.3.cli-migrations-v3
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: [secret stuff]
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: [secret token goes here]
      GRAPHQL_API_AUTH_SECRET: [another secret]
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE: 'unauthorised'
volumes:
  db_data:
```

[image]

There's nothing wrong with the behaviour, authentication works fine - but it's abosloutely hammering firebase which doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Hi friend, could you please file a github bug report on this? I looked and didn't find any duplicates https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed as of hasura/graphql-engine:v2.6.0.cli-migrations-v2, possibly an older verison even